# Intermittent SSL handshake error with Apache HTTP Server

Tags: java, apache, ssl, handshake

I am seeing intermittent SSL handshake errors with Java clients and browsers accessing a site through an Apache HTTP server. This happens rarely, but it breaks builds and impacts user experience every day. The server is configured to establish a secure connection, but to not require a certificate from the client.

I've turned on SSL debug output on both a Java test client and the server (see below). What I am observing is that whenever the handshake exception occurs the server seems to have sent a request for a client certificate. I do not understand why it would ever do so, and why this only happens sporadically. When it does send the certificate request, the error occurs almost always, however I have also captured requests where this succeeded (maybe 1% of the time, with 99% failing).

The client uses Java 8 (1.8.0_31-b13), the Apache HTTP server version is 2.2.19.

Here are snippets from the logs:

1) Apache config excerpt

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCertificateFile <path-to-pem1>
SSLCertificateChainFile <path-to-pem2>
SSLCACertificateFile <path-to-pem3>
SSLVerifyDepth 10
SSLVerifyClient none
```

The .pem files are world-readable.

2) Client log (severly abbreviated)

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
***
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
***
*** Certificate chain
***
*** Diffie-Hellman ServerKeyExchange
*** CertificateRequest
*** ServerHelloDone
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, DH
*** Finished
***
...
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
...
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
```

3) Server log (abbreviated)

```
[info] [client x.x.x.x] Connection to child 1 established (server XXX:443)
[info] Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1866): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 11/11 bytes from BIO#82f6820 [mem: 82c5290] (BIO dump follows)
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX-XX XX XX                 ...........      |
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 245/245 bytes from BIO#82f6820 [mem: 82c529b] (BIO dump follows)
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX-XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX  ................ |
...
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 00f0: XX XX XX XX XX                                   .....            |
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1987): [client x.x.x.x] SSL virtual host for servername XXX found
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 read client hello A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write server hello A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write certificate A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1274): [client x.x.x.x] handing out temporary 1024 bit DH key
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write key exchange A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write certificate request A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 flush data
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#82f6820 [mem: 82c5290] (BIO dump follows)
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: 16 03 01 00 8d                                   .....            |
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 141/141 bytes from BIO#82f6820 [mem: 82c5295] (BIO dump follows)
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX-XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX  ................ |
...
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0080: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX-XX XX XX XX XX           .............    |
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1884): OpenSSL: Write: SSLv3 read client certificate B
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv3 read client certificate B
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv3 read client certificate B
[info] [client x.x.x.x] SSL library error 1 in handshake (server XXX:443)
[info] SSL Library Error: 336105671 error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate No CAs known to server for verification?
[info] [client x.x.x.x] Connection closed to child 1 with abortive shutdown (server XXX:443)
```

In good cases we consistently see no "*** CertificateRequest" on the client and output like this on the server

```
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1987): [client x.x.x.x] SSL virtual host for servername XXX found
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 read client hello A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write server hello A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write certificate A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1274): [client x.x.x.x] handing out temporary 1024 bit DH key
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write key exchange A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write server done A
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 flush data
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#82d82d8 [mem: 82c8790] (BIO dump follows)
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: 16 03 01 00 86                                   .....            |
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 134/134 bytes from BIO#82d82d8 [mem: 82c8795] (BIO dump follows)
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX-XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX  ................ |
...
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0080: XX XX XX XX XX XX                                ......           |
[debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 read client key exchange A
```

Java client code outline:

```
URL url = new URL("https://...");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((user + ":" + pass).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
connection.setReadTimeout(60*1000);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.connect();
```

Run with

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=... -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=... -Djavax.net.debug=all ...
```

Questions:

1. What makes the server send the certificate request, causing the
   ouput "*** CertificateRequest" on the client?
2. Is the setting "SSLVerifyClient none" not preventing the certificate request?
3. Any suggestions on what to look at next?

**Update**: I noticed that the Java client never shows the error when Java 6 is used. The problem occurs with Java 7 and 8, and in Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox. This seems to point to an issue with TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 (see also https://serverfault.com/questions/513961/how-to-disable-tls-1-1-1-2-in-apache "OpenSSL v1.0.1 has some known issues with TLSv1.2"). I will try to at least check if disabling TLSv1.1/2 in the Java client will make the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

> What makes the server send the certificate request, causing the ouput "*** CertificateRequest" on the client?

A call to `SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list` at the server. Its a list of distinguished names. Also see the [`SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_add_client_CA.html).

The server will also need to call `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` to establish the trust in the CAs. Also see [`SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html).

---

> Is the setting "SSLVerifyClient none" not preventing the certificate request?

Possibly. From the [`SSL_CTX_set_verify` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html), you need `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` and possibly `SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT`.

---

> Any suggestions on what to look at next?

You should show your relevant Java code.

You should state the OpenSSL version used by the server and the client.

Comment: It's sent to the client in the CertificateRequest. No reason to send it otherwise.

Comment: Added Java sample code, OpenSSL not used there. I have no access to the actual machine. The sysadmin tells me "OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014, <3rdpartycompanyname> extensions 3.0.16.0" is installed. I assume Apache uses shared libs.

Answer (score 0):

> What makes the server send the certificate request, causing the ouput "*** CertificateRequest" on the client?

Somewhere you have `SSLVerifyClient` set to 'optional' or higher, possibly in a .htaccess file, which is why you can't find it in the configuration files. This overrides `SSLVerifyClient none' set globally.

Comment: The sysadmin tells me there are no .htaccess files around. "SSLVerifyClient none" however was only configured in the <VirtualHost> section. Moved it up into httpd.conf (globally) - looks promising, but I will know more only tomorrow. Still puzzles me why the problem should occur only sporadically.

Comment: Somewhere or other it is configured higher than 'none'. Otherwise the CertificateRequest would not be sent. There is no room for any doubt about this.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated! Due to circumstances outside my control progress is agonizingly slow. I asked for configuration of mod_info so the config can be displayed at runtime; maybe it will show an unexpected SSLVerifyClient setting. I am producing sporadic certificate requests by firing up a new JVM and accessing the same URL over and over. A fraction of these calls show the certificate request and fail. Any idea why this would only occur sporadically? As far as I understand the certificate request is part of the server's SSL state, why would it react differently to the same request?

Comment: The configuration des not show "SSLVerifClient" set to anything else than "none". I think we are seeing an issue in mod_ssl or the openssl implementation.

Answer (score 0):

After long and tedious debugging and analysis I would like to report the findings. The problem is related to the first `ClientHello` message of the TLS handshake as sent by the client.

Java 7 and Java 8 clients (and probably all modern browsers) use the "Server Name Indication" (SNI) extension. The problem only occurs when this extension is used. Java 6 clients don't send it, and the problem never occurred there. The problem occurred with TLSv1 and TLSv1.2 - we never observed TLSv1.1 requests so I cannot comment.

For Java 7 and 8 clients to prevent the issue we can set `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` which stops the client sending the SNI extension.

We will try to change the `httpd.conf` configuration (and included files) to see if we can get the server to behave well. I may post information if we're successful, i.e. if there is a server-side workaround for this. The above mentioned Java switch is a client-side workaround which is at least good enough for our nightly builds.

Comment: i have this exact problem on tomcat 8.5 with jre 8. Unfortunately disabling SNI doesn't fix it (at least in my case).

Comment: @spy I'm seeing similar issues with tomcat 8.5 and jre8 -- intermittent handshake failures.  Did you ever figure out what was happening?

Comment: @toppie.c in my case it was Openssl.  Turned that off and it was good to go